# Why, when I read the bootstrap3css, do you change the value that the browser returned by jQuery offset method?

Tags: jquery, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Why, when I read the bootstrap3css, do you change the value that the browser returned by jQuery offset method?**

Value that the browser returned by jQuery offset method becomes ***point***.

Which is correct?

How does it to match?

---

**Chrome**

44.0.2403.157 m

---

**Do not read bootstrap3css**

```
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2000 400" width="500" height="400">
  <rect id="hoge" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
</svg>
<script>
  console.log($("#hoge").offset()); //Object {top: 59, left: 21.5}
</script>
```

---

**Read bootstrap3css**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 2000 400" width="500" height="400">
  <rect id="hoge" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
</svg>
<script>
  console.log($("#hoge").offset()); //Object {top: 50.75, left: 13.449999809265137}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because bootstrap sets the `body`'s margin to `0`:

```
//in bootstrap.min.css:
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Without loading bootstrap, chrome sets the `body`'s margin to `8px` by default:

```
//user agent stylesheet(chrome)
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Okay here's a fix. For the svg to be of the same position whether you load bootstrap or not, just create a custom stylesheet like a `style.css` then add these lines like the ones in `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
//custom body style    
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to load it in your page.

Comment: Thanks and I add user agent stylesheet(chrome).But the result is Object {top: 58.75, left: 21.450000762939453}.